# alphanumeric strings can be also URI or IRI?

Tags: uri, iri

I have data with alphanumeric ids like 9625ea21a1bf1be22963576fcdfd863d.
Can I say this is also an IRI (internationalized resource identifier) or URI value?

All URI examples are like aaa.txt, aaa/bbb.html, or protocol://aaa/bbb.ext#tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (which is [IETF’s Internet Standard for URIs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std66)) what a URI is.

The [generic URI syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) is:

> ```
> scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
> ```

As you can see, a URI requires at least a "scheme" component, followed by the `:` character, followed by components defined under "hier-part".

So `9625ea21a1bf1be22963576fcdfd863d` can’t possibly be a URI.

It could of course be a [relative reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2), namely a *relative-path reference*. For example, if you have the following hyperlink in a HTML document with the URI `file:///folder1/folder2/document1`, the target URI would be `file:///folder1/folder2/9625ea21a1bf1be22963576fcdfd863d`:

```html
<a href="9625ea21a1bf1be22963576fcdfd863d">link</a>
```

(For IRIs, which are defined in [RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987), it’s essentially the same.)